# How to port existing distributed service application to DCOS?

Tags: c++, linux, mesos, mesosphere

so there is a set of applications that position itself as a distributed cluster O/S called **DCOS**.

It has an **`MPI`** and `spark` running on top of it.

I am a developer and I have a set of distributed services running connected via `socket` or **`ZeroMQ`** communication system.

**How can I port my existing services to DCOS?**

Meaning use it's communication facilities instead of `sockets`/`zmq`.

**Is there any API \ Docs on how not to run it but develop for it?**

Comment: Your first question is too broad. Your second question is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to get your application to run on DCOS (and/or Mesos).

First for legacy applications you can use the [marathon framework](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon)  which you can view as kind of the init system of DCOS/Mesos.
If you need more elaborate applications and want to really program against the apis you would write a mesos framework: see the [framework development guide](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/app-framework-development-guide/) for more details.
For deeper integration of your framework into DCOS as for example using the package repository/ command line install option check out/contact [mesosphere](https://mesosphere.com/) for more details.

Hope this helps!
Joerg